# Custom view in Django admin: NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to add custom view for "Add" action in admin panel. Ihave written following code and got an error

```
 "NoReverseMatch Reverse for 'app_list' with arguments '()' 
 and keyword arguments '{'app_label': ''}' not found."
```

```
class UserDictionaryAdmin(BaseAdmin):
    list_display = ('word', 'user', 'word_state')

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'default'

    def add_view(self, request, form_url=None, extra_content=None):
        return render_to_response('admin/userdictionary_add.html', self.model._meta)
```

`urls.py` wasn't modified.

Also I tried the same construction without `'self.model._meta'` without any positive result.

Comment: Looks like you need to pass the arguments for app_list in your context. See http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1921/.